# pushing value into an array within $scope returns undefined

Tags: angularjs

**Okay...I feel really stupid now. Please ignore my question. The example works in fiddler so it really is a problem somewhere else. I'm just going to try fixing this myself. Thanks. Fixed it... I had a line of code above that used the $resource service to create a new $scope.group object which replaced the original $scope.group.admin. I'll delete this question later**

JsFiddler: http://jsfiddle.net/ovLzwez7/

I'm going to revise my question a bit because this is a scope issue.

In my controller I have these

```
$scope.group = {}
$scope.group.admin = [7,8];

//Works
console.log($scope.group.admin)  //[7,8]
$scope.group.admin.push(7);
console.log($scope.group.admin) //[7,8,7]

//Doesn't work
$scope.createGroup = function(){
   console.log($scope.group.admin) //undefined   
   $scope.group.admin.push(7);
  //TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
  console.log($scope.group.admin) //doesn't print to output, program ends because of the error above

}

$scope.createGroup();
```

createGroup is instantly called when controller is loaded. It looks like inside createGroup(), $scope.group.admin is not an array (undefined). Can someone explain this scope issue and how I can overcome this? In this example, (sorry for the abrupt change), I'm not manipulating any html, I'm just using console.log and a function that instantly loads.I thought that $scope was a singleton. So shouldn't it reference the same $scope?

Comment: You are right that is is likely a scope issue and without more code, specifically the HTML, there is no way to know. I would suggest trying to recreate this issue on something like Fiddler or Plunker

Comment: You should show us your HTML and which controllers are in play here. This sounds like you're trying to do it from a different scope, therefore not finding the `addAdmin(x)` function.

Answer (score 0):

you should use `ng-keypress` directive to fire an angular method bound to your scope.

`<input name="username" ng-keypress="createGroup($event)">`

```
$scope.createGroup = function(event){

  if(e.which === 13) {
     $scope.addAdmin(7234)
  }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This code below is out the $scope.apply it is simple javascript code which doesnot come under angular criteria so you need to either use ng-keypress or use $scope.apply() function to make it work.

```
     addAdmin.addEventListener('keyup', function(e){

          // If the key enter pressed (13) then add to list
          if(e.keyCode === 13) {
             $scope.addAdmin(7234)
          }
         })
      }
```

How to use $scope.$apply():-

```
 addAdmin.addEventListener('keyup', function(e){

          // If the key enter pressed (13) then add to list
          if(e.keyCode === 13) {
            $scope.apply(function(){
               $scope.addAdmin(7234)
             }
          });
         })
      }
```

Comment: There's no reason to use scope apply, his issue is probably different scopes.

Comment: addEventListener() is not come under angular $scope.apply() its a simple javascript  function so it cannot allow you to use $scope inside it.

Comment: The entire use of javascript here is wrong, it should be fixed instead of fixing with workarounds.

Comment: Yes I am agree with you thats why i firstly suggest use ng-keypress and then use this but if in any case he or she cannot do that then he can use second option.